# Find missing day from array of dates javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I am getting an array of day dates from an API:

```
0:{date: "2016-11-17T00:00:00",…}
1:{date: "2016-11-18T00:00:00",…}
2:{date: "2016-11-19T00:00:00",…}
3:{date: "2016-11-21T00:00:00",…}
4:{date: "2016-11-22T00:00:00",…}
5:{date: "2016-11-23T00:00:00",…}
```

In this example the array is missing this date:

```
{date: "2016-11-20T00:00:00",…}
```

What is the best way to find a missing day from an array of dates in Javascript or Angular?

So that I later would be able to pass it to a datepicker as a disabled day.

Comment: What (working) algorithm did you try so far?

Comment: what is `...` meaning ??

Comment: I am in the process of thinking about it: Using two for loops

Comment: ```...``` means unnecessary information

Comment: is the data sorted?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30299908/337128

Comment: yes it is sorted from nearest to most far away date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out:

1. First you can sort the array (in case it is not so) using `Array.prototype.sort`
2. Then use `Array.prototype.reduce` and a `hash table` to find the missing dates

Demo given in snippet below:

```js
var array=[
  {date:"2016-11-17T00:00:00"},
  {date:"2016-11-19T00:00:00"},
  {date:"2016-11-18T00:00:00"},
  {date:"2016-11-21T00:00:00"},
  {date:"2016-11-22T00:00:00"},
  {date:"2016-11-23T00:00:00"},
  {date:"2016-11-27T00:00:00"}
];

var result = array.sort(function(a,b){
   return Date.parse(a.date) - Date.parse(b.date);
}).reduce(function(hash){
  return function(p,c){
    var missingDaysNo = (Date.parse(c.date) - hash.prev) / (1000 * 3600 * 24);
    if(hash.prev && missingDaysNo > 1) {
      for(var i=1;i<missingDaysNo;i++)
        p.push(new Date(hash.prev+i*(1000 * 3600 * 24)));
    }
    hash.prev = Date.parse(c.date);
    return p;
  };
}(Object.create(null)),[]);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important;}
```

Comment: @alereisan let me know your thoughts on this... This works if the dates are not in order and also if more than one date is skipped... Note that if more than one days are skipped in succession, that will be handled too...

Answer (score 1):

Create a new array missingDates[]

Iterate over the array (from your API) using a for loop

```
for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    var date1 = convert your array item (with index i) to a date
    var date2 = convert your array item (with index i + 1) to a date (keep in mind, index i + 1 cant be > than array.length)

    //calculate diffDays between the 2 dates, if diff is > 1, you have a missing date
    var missingDate = create your missing date (use your date1 variable + 1Day)

    //add misingDate to missingDates[] array
    missingDates.push(missingDate)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do a method `getMissingDate` to return `null` if there is not missing date or return the `Date` object if there is a difference between to dates bigger than one day:

```js
var arr1 = [{date: "2016-11-17T00:00:00"}, {date: "2016-11-18T00:00:00"}, {date: "2016-11-19T00:00:00"}, {date: "2016-11-21T00:00:00"}, {date: "2016-11-22T00:00:00"}, {date: "2016-11-23T00:00:00"}],
    arr2 = [{date: "2016-11-17T00:00:00"}, {date: "2016-11-18T00:00:00"}, {date: "2016-11-19T00:00:00"}, {date: "2016-11-20T00:00:00"}, {date: "2016-11-21T00:00:00"}, {date: "2016-11-22T00:00:00"}, {date: "2016-11-23T00:00:00"}],
    getMissingDate = function(arr) {
      var result = null;
      for (var i = 0, l = arr.length - 1; i < l; i++) {
        var current = new Date(arr[i].date),
            next = new Date(arr[i + 1].date);

        if (1 < Math.ceil(Math.abs(next.getTime() - current.getTime()) / (1000 * 3600 * 24))) {
          result = new Date(current.setDate(current.getDate() + 1));
          break;
        } 
      }

      return result;
    };

console.log('arr1:', getMissingDate(arr1));
console.log('arr2:', getMissingDate(arr2));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var array=[
  {date:"2016-01-01T00:00:00"},
  {date:"2016-03-01T00:00:00"},
  {date:"2016-04-01T00:00:00"},
  {date:"2016-07-01T00:00:00"},
  {date:"2016-09-01T00:00:00"},
  {date:"2016-11-01T00:00:00"},
  {date:"2016-12-01T00:00:00"}
];

var result = array.sort(function(a,b){
   return Date.parse(a.date) - Date.parse(b.date);
}).reduce(function(hash){
  return function(p,c){
    var missingMonthsNo= (Date.parse(c.date) - hash.prev) / (1000 * 3600 * 24);
    if(hash.prev && missingMonthsNo> 1) {
      for(var i=1;i<missingMonthsNo;i++)
        p.push(new Date(hash.prev+i*(1000 * 3600 * 24)));
    }
    hash.prev = Date.parse(c.date);
    return p;
  };
}(Object.create(null)),[]);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important;}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).